# Python re-instantiate model in shared controller instance

Tags: python, reference, controller, parameter-passing

I try to build a gui which involves multiple frames which should all access and interact with the same Model instance. Therefore, I create a Controller instance `ctrl`, which is passed to every frame.

Instead of using `self.ctrl.model` for every model interaction, I introduced `self.model = self.ctrl.model` during frame initialization to increase readability. This was working fine so far for all changes in the model, i.e. all changes were propagated to the controller and all other frames. However, one application requires to re-instantiate the model. As variables are passed by assignment, the re-instantiation leads to a new `Model()` instance, which is assigned to `self.model` in the specific frame, leaving it uncoupled from `self.ctrl.model`. What is the best way to re-instantiate the Model such that all changes are propagated to the Controller and the other frames?

```
class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self.par = "init"    

class Controller():
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = Model()

    def state(self):
        print("ctrl  | id:", id(self.model), "| par:", self.model.par)

class FrameA():
    def __init__(self, parent, ctrl):
        self.parent = parent
        self.ctrl = ctrl
        self.model = self.ctrl.model

    def modify(self):
        self.model.par = "modify"
        print("frame | id:", id(self.model), "| par:", self.model.par)

    def newmodel(self):
        self.model = Model()
        print("frame | id:", id(self.model), "| par:", self.model.par)

ctrl = Controller()
frameA = FrameA(None,ctrl)
ctrl.state()
frameA.modify()
ctrl.state() # changes in frameA propagate to ctrl
frameA.newmodel()
ctrl.state() # changes in frameA do not propagate to ctrl anymore
```

Output:

```
ctrl  | id: 2040845455712 | par: init
frame | id: 2040845455712 | par: modify
ctrl  | id: 2040845455712 | par: modify
frame | id: 2040845245128 | par: init
ctrl  | id: 2040845455712 | par: modify
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the controller if you are directly accessing the model inside it? I think this breaks the MVC principles.

Comment: I'm using the controller to basically bundle different models/ a general config (I showed only one model in the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a beauty way of accomplishing what you want is using getters and setters.
Example:

```
class Model:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

class Controller:
  def __init__(self, model):
    self.model = model

class Frame:
  def __init__(self, controller):
    self.controller = controller
    self.model = controller.model

  @property
  def model(self):
    return self.__model

  @model.setter
  def model(self, model):
    self.__model = model
    self.controller.model = model


controller = Controller(Model())
frame = Frame(controller)

print (id(frame.model), id(frame.controller.model))
frame.model = Model()
print (id(frame.model), id(frame.controller.model))
```

Comment: that's a great workaround! As I have to re-instantiate the model only at one place, I can do this with `self.ctrl.model = Model()` und use the getter for the rest

Answer (score 1):

I could think of 2 possible solutions to obtain desired behaviour, however there might be other/ smarter changes:

- don't be lazy and refer to the model always by `self.ctrl.model`
- do the re-instantiation referring the controller `self.ctrl.model = Model()` and introduce a new `init_model()` method in each frame which sets `self.model = self.ctrl.model` again, such that the abbreviation `self.model` can be used as previously